# R - Get averages from column combinations

Tags: r

I am having a hard time finding answers/examples on SO of what I'm trying to do, which is the following:

Example data frame where I've got values (1) as well as NAs in cells:

```
Obvs | Cond1 | Cond2 | Cond3 | Cond4 | Value
---------------------------------------------
1    | 1     | NA    | 1     | NA    | 3
2    | NA    | 1     | 1     | NA    | 2
3    | 1     | NA    | 1     | NA    | 9
4    | 1     | NA    | NA    | 1     | 9
5    | NA    | 1     | NA    | NA    | 7
6    | NA    | NA    | NA    | 1     | 7
7    | NA    | NA    | 1     | NA    | 10
8    | NA    | 1     | NA    | NA    | 9
9    | NA    | NA    | NA    | 1     | 4
10   | 1     | NA    | NA    | NA    | 4
11   | NA    | NA    | 1     | 1     | 3
12   | NA    | 1     | 1     | NA    | 5
```

My goal is to get the average of rows that satisfy each column combination with a value (i.e., value of 1) in them. For example, observations in Obvs 1 and 3 both have values in Cond1 and Cond3 while the other Cond cols are NA , so I would want to create a separate column that would hold that average of those two Obvs' Values. So output would be something like below where it shows the average Value of all Cond combinations available in the dataset. Is there any way for R to find all of those combinations elegantly (without me manually specifying them) and spit out the average Value if it satisfies a specific combination?  This would be for a large dataset with many more columns in it to consider.

```
Cond1 | Cond2 | Cond3 | Cond4 | Avg_Value
1     | NA    | 1     | NA    | 6
NA    | 1     | 1     | NA    | 3.5
1     | NA    | NA    | 1     | 9
NA    | 1     | NA    | NA    | 8
NA    | NA    | NA    | 1     | 5.5
NA    | NA    | 1     | NA    | 10
1     | NA    | NA    | NA    | 4
NA    | NA    | 1     | 1     | 3
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group_by` and `summarise` from package `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Cond1,Cond2,Cond3,Cond4)%>%
  summarise(Avg_Value=mean(Value))

    Cond1   Cond2   Cond3   Cond4 Avg_Value
    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1  1       NA      1       NA           6.0
2  1       NA      NA      1            9.0
3  1       NA      NA      NA           4.0
4  NA      1       1       NA           3.5
5  NA      1       NA      NA           8.0
6  NA      NA      1       1            3.0
7  NA      NA      1       NA          10.0
8  NA      NA      NA      1            5.5
```

Comment: Thanks @HubertL!  That is what tripped me up--the group_by() part. I will gladly take the downvote that a couple people have given me--I realized I was quite close to solving this on my own!

Comment: To avoid downvotes, it's better to provide the data in a machine readable format (instead of /  in addition to human readable format). It's important to add your (not working) code too